# Error Late Binding to New Outlook on Windows 11

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have been using the same Excel VBA code for Outlook Late Binding for quite some time.

Today while my Outlook decided to "Try" the New Outlook, Excel was unable to detect the Outlook App or create it.

[image]

The code I have been using is listed below.

Has anyone else encountered this error and was able to find a workaround?
All of my **Google** searches and Microsoft White pages have returned zero successful matches.

***Code***

```
On Error Resume Next
Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If OutApp Is Nothing Then
    ' try to create an Outlook instance
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    OutlookIsOpen = False
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

The new Outlook (project Monarch) doesn't provide any COM interfaces. That is a lightweight web-based application which doesn't support automation. The only possible way to extend such applications is by using web add-ins, see [Outlook add-ins documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/) for more information.

Comment: Do you know if Microsoft going to force everyone to switch to this version? Or are they going to allow using the current Outlook?

Comment: They didn't decide yet.

Answer (score 1):

The new Outlook does not have an API similar to the Outlook Object Model. Web addins (JS) is the only way to interact with it programmatically.

Comment: Oh Oh, where can I learn more about Web Addins (JS) ?

Comment: You can start at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator